# Jquery wookmark plugin keep order

Tags: javascript, jquery, wookmark

I'm using the wookmark plugin for jquery to display a list of products in a tile view. Also, I have this "tiles" comming in an ajax calling (endless scrooling).

When I'm getting a new page I'm recalling the container in order to apply to the "new page" the pluggin.

The problems I'm facing with this plugins are: if the number of tiles are not enought to fill the container, the plugin will put align to center (imagine a row that has space for 4 tiles but only has 2, the pluggin will put this two in center)

Also, sometimes when fetching a new page, the tiles are reorder.

Someone knows how to force always the tiles to be align left (the free space will be on the right side of the container) and how to "turn off" the ordering?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are instantiating a new Object when you pull your new page. Instead, try re-using the original Object so you won't have to reapply your defaults every time.

Comment: How to do that? When I receive the new page I run $('#tiles li').wookmarkInstance.clear(); and then I call again  $('#tiles li').wookmark({...}) again. Is this wrong?